# How to get new terminal windows to have node version 12 instead of 10?

Tags: npm, nvm

I've installed node version 12 using the below commands.

```
$ nvm install 12 -g
# note - nvm use 12.13.1 has same effect
v12.13.1 is already installed.
Now using node v12.13.1 (npm v6.12.1)
```

When I type `$ node -v` to confirm the node version, the command line reads `v12.13.1`.

I have also set it as my default node version.

```
$ nvm alias default 12.13.1
default -> 12.13.1 (-> v12.13.1)
```

Yet when I open a new window I still see version 10.

```
$ node -v
v10.17.0
```

and I have to

```
$ nvm use 12
```

every time I open a new window

and then I have

```
$ node -v
v12.13.1
```

How can I have 12 be my default without doing use every time ?

This is on Ubuntu, my `.bashrc` includes:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Comment: Type `where node` in your command line. What does it log?

Answer (score 0):

I removed npm by removing the  `~/.npm` folder and then reinstalled npm with:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
```

and version 12 of node with

```
nvm install 12
node -v
```

This fixed it and now new terminal windows now show

```
node -v
v12.13.1
```